# Should I backup DBF file while it is open?

Tags: dbase

I need to create a little program that creates a backup copy of some DBF files on demand. the files are used by a custom designed Web application. Is it safe to copy a dbf file while it is open or do I need to close the web server so the files are released before safely creating a backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You may end up with corruption in the file when you try to restore it, if it even backs up.